# Applying a function to all columns of a data.table together with a group-by

Tags: r, group-by, data.table

I have a `data.table` with a large number of rows. I want to group the data table by one particular column, and I want to apply the same aggregation function to all the other columns. What is the appropriate way of doing that?

Here is some sample code to set up a data table that looks similar to what I have.

```
my.table.tmp <- matrix(runif(5000*95), nrow=5000)
my.table <- data.table(my.table.tmp)
my.table[, gbc:=rep(c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'), 1000)]
```

I want to group the table by the factor column `gbc`, and I want that all the remaining 95 columns should be aggregated by a function, let's say `mean`.

I see that

```
my.table[, lapply(.SD, mean), by=gbc]
```

gives me a table with the correct dimensions, but I am not sure if this is doing the right thing. If it is doing the right thing, can someone help me by breaking down what's happening here?

Comment: I think it's right going by your description. It is calculating the `mean` for each column in `my.table` other than `gbc` - represented by `.SD`, grouped by `gbc`.

Comment: What does `.SD` do here? In particular, `lapply(.SD, myfunction)` treats each subsetted column as an element of a list, and then applies `myfunction` to that list element as input?

Comment: Yep, that is correct. `.SD` is just all the subsetted columns for each group, and since a `data.frame/data.table` is just a `list` stuck together as columns, `lapply` will loop over each column applying the `myfunction`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your description sounds correct `.SD` is just all the subsetted columns for each `by=` group, and since a `data.frame/data.table` is just a `list` stuck together as columns, `lapply` will loop over each column applying the `myfunction`